# Trying to run VMware 8.0.2 on 11.10 x64?

Tags: installation, 64-bit

I have downloaded VMware 8 for Linux. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 x64. I am very new to linux, and I am having trouble getting Vmware 8 to install. I know that there must be a sudo command to get the VMware to unpack, but I don't know what it is. Can anyone help a extremely new Linux guy with this?

Answer (score 1):

To install VMware workstation in Ubuntu x64 run the following command:

```
sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle
```

And then follow the setup instructions.